# Perl confused with script

Tags: perl

Write a perl script that takes one argument, the name of a file or directory. The script should call the stat function and print the resulting data along with a one line explanation of each field.

```
my $args;
$args=@ARGV;

if ($args<1)
{
    die("Expecting a filename");
}

sub showstat
{
      print " $_[0] dev, device number of filesystem\n";
      print " $_[1] ino,      inode number\n";
      print " $_[2] mode,     file mode  (type and permissions)\n";
      print " $_[3] nlink,    number of (hard) links to the file\n";
}

my $filename=$ARGV[0];
if (open (TESTFILE,$filename))
{
    my @filedata= stat(TESTFILE);

    &showstat(@filedata);
    close (TESTFILE);
}
else
{
    print "error on open $filename";
}
```

My question is if `$args=@ARGV`, shouldn't `$ARGV[0]` equal to `$args[0]` instead of `$filename=$ARGV[0]`? Why not?

and under where it says `@showstat(@filedata)`, why do you put the ampersand? (i know by definition it is a subroutine), but can I get a clarification what the actual function do in here?

Comment: Didn't you ask a similar questions a while ago?

Comment: @UlrichDangel no, he has asked 3, all closed of course.

Comment: @Luc, programming questions are off topic here, try them at stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 5):

Perl is context sensitive. If you assign to a scalar variable

```
$args = @ARGV
```

the right hand side value is evaluated in scalar context, i.e. the array returns its size.

Using the ampersand for subroutine calls is a Perl 4 habit. Nowadays, there are only few cases where you really need the ampersand, e.g. in this case, it can be safely deleted.